# why molecules gain energy when heated?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

molecules in solid or liquid or gas gain kinetic energy when heated. why is it like this? I request explanation  in details please

Comment: Kinetic energy of molecules **is** heat. Why the molecules gain heat when heated, really?

Comment: Though this question may seem simple or self explanatory to many, I try to support others in their curiosity :)

Comment: @IvanNeretin, kinetic energy of molecules together with their potential energy is *internal energy*, heat is one of the means of changing  this energy.

Answer (score 3):

**Heat is a form of kinetic energy**.  Thus, the heating of a molecule is simply the transfer of energy from the heat source to the molecular bonds and electrons.

Comment: I would be careful in calling heat "a form of energy". It is one of the two *means of energy transfer* for the case of a closed thermodynamic system (with another one being work). Or, the amount of energy spontaneously flowing from/to a closed system due to a temperature difference between the system and it surroundings by means other than through work.

Comment: Then, transferring heat changes internal energy of a system, which, in fact, is the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of the particles that form the system.